# meaning of comp and blockid in azure storage rest api

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I noticed two query parameters `comp` and `blockid` appearing in rest API call to Azure blob storage.

```
https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/file.txt?comp=REDACTED&blockid=REDACTED

https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/file.txt?comp=REDACTED
```

I guess `blockid` means the id of a block which is a part of a large blob. But what is the meaning of `comp` here? What are the differences between the above two rest api requests (HTTP PUT)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the following MS-Docs link, comp is an abbreviation of component, which means a component of the resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#shared-key-lite-and-table-service-format-for-2009-09-19-and-later